# Launch a dynamo graph (.dyn) file from python script

Tags: ironpython, pyrevit

Is it possible to launch a revit dynamo .dyn file through a python script (PyRevit extension)?

Can someone share a basic example.

We have many dynamo scripts tested and in production, it would be very help to launch them from buttons on a PyRevit ribbon along with other buttons that run python scripts for more complex tasks.

Comment: if you have pyRevit 4.6 and above, instead of a python script, create a script.dyn file inside your pyRevit extension bundle and pyRevit will run that with Dynamo. Watch this: https://youtu.be/SGsw_Bbrx0c?t=370

Comment: OK, started trying this, some dynamo scripts not working right out of the gate, will continue to test.  

One (minor thing) i do like about using a python script Instead of launching a .dyn script is that with the python scrip it seams you can insert return characters into the button name (text) as it appears below the icon in the ribbon, haven't figure out how to do this using .dyn for a script, but honestly I need to spend more time reading the docs....I will say this is a wonderful thing you have developed - thank you for your efforts.

Comment: This was just implemented. Coming soon: https://github.com/eirannejad/pyRevit/issues/474

Comment: still can't seam to run the simplest dynamo scripts from a pyrevit extension bundle. No error message or anything, just spinning wheel and no changes....